# How to send email automatically in Laravel 5

Tags: php, email, laravel

I just build  a simple system information. I want to send email automatically to user every Monday. How to send email automatically in Laravel 5, is there a tool that can solve my problem?

@bogdan this is my code

**Controller**

```
public function send_email(){               
    $date = getdate();
    $date_now = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('now'));
    $date_exp = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+6 day'));

    $certificate_data = Certificate::where('expired_date', '<=', $date_exp)->where('expired_date', '>=', $date_now)->get();

    foreach($certificate_data as $key => $certificate){
        $student_data = $certificate->student;
        $student_company = Student::find($student_data->id)->company;
        $data = ['com_nama' => $student_company->name, 'nama' => $student_data->name, 'judul'=>$certificate->title,'exp_date'=>$certificate->expired_date];
        $path_file = Config::get('custom_path.certificates').'/'. $certificate->image;
        $test = Mail::send('emails.notification', $data, function($m) use($student_company,$path_file,$student_data,$certificate){
            $m->to($student_company->email);
            $m->subject('Pemberitahuan Waktu Kadaluarsa Sertifikat');
            $m->attach($path_file, ['as' => $student_data->name.'-'.$certificate->title]);
        });                         
    }

}
```

here the error

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of [Artisan Scheduling](http://laravel.com/docs/master/artisan#scheduling-artisan-commands). In your case something like this should do:

```
$schedule->call(function()
{
    // Send emails here

})->mondays();
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but can you tell me more? maybe more complete? sory for my english...

Comment: The documentation I linked in my answer explains everything you need to do to set up the scheduler and where to place the code I wrote, just read the **Scheduling Artisan Commands** section. If you need to know more about sending emails in Laravel just read the [Mail Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/mail), it explains it very clearly.

Comment: @thanks bogdan, you're great. now i have a new problem, i want to attach some image to the email, but there is a error.

 [ErrorException]
  fopen(assets/images/certificates/05042015060646.JPG): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

it show at my command windows

whats wrong?

if i dont use schedule, it's run prefectly(attachment image is success)

Comment: I would need to see the code you are using before I can give any advice. You can edit your question to include the code, or post a new question for that specific issue.